# mysql solving a query using syntax 1999

Tags: mysql

```
desc sales;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| OrderNo  | varchar(6)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| SaleDate | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| StaffNo  | varchar(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CustNo   | varchar(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Invoiced | decimal(2,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
desc staff;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| StaffNo      | varchar(6)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Lastname     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Firstname    | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Hire_date    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Location     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SupervisorNo | varchar(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Salary       | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Commission   | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Q:
List the names of employees that made sales on September 23, 2014.
I want the result to be shown like this

```
 +----------+------------+
| lastname | saledate   |
+----------+------------+
| Zambini  | 2014-09-23 |
| Zambini  | 2014-09-23 |
| Zambini  | 2014-09-23 |
| Zambini  | 2014-09-23 |
| Vidoni   | 2014-09-23 |
| Vidoni   | 2014-09-23 |
| Vidoni   | 2014-09-23 |
| Vidoni   | 2014-09-23 |
| Coudray  | 2014-09-23 |
| Coudray  | 2014-09-23 |
| Coudray  | 2014-09-23 |
| Coudray  | 2014-09-23 |
```

I know how to do it in standard syntax but my teacher wants us to get it using syntax 1999 and using aliases

I tried this method but its wrong

```
select s.lastname Name, s.saledate Date
   -> from staff s JOIN sales s
   -> ON s.saledate = '2014-09-23';
ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 's'
```

Comment: In lieu of someone doing your homework for you, can you post what you have or what you think it should be so we can support you through your learning?

Comment: just change the alias of the table `sales` to `t` or anything else and it will work. you can read about `alias` @ [Standard docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#idm45178939243680)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT lastname Name, saledate Date
FROM staff 
NATURAL JOIN sales 
WHERE saledate = '2014-09-23';
```

If you're afraid that `NATURAL JOIN` is not mentioned in SQL-1999 (which I personally strongly doubt), use

```
SELECT lastname Name, saledate Date
FROM staff 
JOIN sales ON staff.StaffNo = sales.StaffNo  
WHERE saledate = '2014-09-23';
```

Comment: I think this is the standard way to syntax 1999 are you sure ??

Comment: @AbdulazizAlsurikh I have no "SQL 3" standard text. But you have tagged your question as mysql-relative. MySQL 3.23.17+ (~ Jan 2001) support NATURAL JOIN.